# Cloned jQuery draggable can't be dropped on itself

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

Using jQuery UI, I have a div `foo` which is both draggable and droppable, and a div `bar` which is only droppable.  The dragging happens with the `helper: 'clone'` option turned on, so the original `foo` isn't actually moving.  When I drop the cloned `foo` on top of the original `foo`, the `drop: function` doesn't get called.

This seems weird, because it works when I drop the cloned `foo` onto `bar`.  It also works to drop other draggables onto `foo`.  The only problem is that I can't drop `foo` onto itself.

I just said foo and bar and draggable and droppable so many times that even I'm confused, but this example should clear things up:

http://jsfiddle.net/5KATZ/

If you try to drag the first box onto the second or third, it works.  But if instead of dropping it onto the second box, you start dragging it, then try to drop it onto itself, nothing happens.  If this is how things are supposed to work, then what am I doing wrong?  If this is a bug in jQuery UI, then can you think of any good workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

This one works better: http://jsfiddle.net/kW369/, I've left the old one too.

Nice question! This is the default behaviour in jQuery and I think it's right that it works this way... it is a strange thing to have the need to drop an item onto itself. Anyway try [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEQAL/) which is a partial solution to your problem.

It works by detecting the position of the dragged div and see it if collapses with the first div position. I know this is not the most clear solution but it's the only one I was able to come up with. Also, this has a bug because the position gets calculated using the top left corner of the div so if you are dropping the first div onto the second by placing the mouse inside the second div BUT the top left corner of the div you're dragging is on top of the first one it will behave like you dropped it onto both divs. You should use mouse position instead of ui.position['top'] and ui.position['top'] and left to detect the position more precisely.

Comment: Very nice! That is a very clever approach, and I managed to learn about jQuery's `position()` function in the process.  I realize that needing to be able to drop a draggable on itself is probably a rare request, but in my JavaScript implementation of MasterMind, if you pick up a piece to move it, then decide to put it back down in the same spot, it disappears, which is weird.  See: http://martinsmucker.com/mastermind

Comment: The strangeness is not in the ergonomics but actually in jQuery.  I believe all agree that dragging an object nearly zero distance should have no result.  The problem comes when dropping "anywhere but" the original position has meaning.  E.g. deleting tools from a toolbar by dragging them off of it.  The original location needs to be another droppable target.  Then that drop handler reverts, while the stop handler for the surrounding everywhere-else has actual effects.